# Restore libxml2 to Yosemite

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, library

Ok, so here is the deal. I was working on two projects at the same time and I mistakenly:

```
rm -rf /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
```

I have another copy of libxml2 thankfully (the other project, homebrew install libxml2). That copy is in /usr/local/opt/libxml/lib. For the life of me I can not get cp /usr/local/opt/libxml2/lib/libxml2.2.dylib /usr/lib to work. It always says:

```
/usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib Read-only Filesystem
```

Please can anyone help? I have tried cp -S, -R, -F and I can't get it to cp or mv. I just need to write that lib back and I should be good to go. I don't know what I was thinking when I did that. Running Yosemite 10.10.2, Late-2011 mbp. Libxml2 from homebrew is 2.9.2 I think if it makes a difference.

Comment: The version of libxml in Homebrew is I think different from the one in OS X - you need to reinstall OS X and not do that link

Comment: Um ... you did try to use `sudo`, didn't you?

Comment: You mean there is no way I can get a libxml2 from another Yosemite? I am forced to reinstall? Yes, I did use sudo

Comment: @RinconRex try `/sbin/mount -uw /` before copying. In single user mode the file system is mounted read-only. Your mileage starting OS X with the homebrew libxml2.2dylib may vary...

Comment: OMG You are a genius sir. It worked! I tried mount -o remount,rw / but nothing. Yours did the trick, back up and running!

Comment: Hmm now continue with my answer to restore the original dylib

Comment: Yes, thank you. I will restore the Yosemite dynamic lib. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Enter `/sbin/mount -uw /` and copy 'libxml2.2.dylib' from '/usr/local/opt/libxml/lib/' to '/usr/lib/'
- Restart your Mac and restore the original file:
- Download [Pacifist](https://www.charlessoft.com/) (i think it's a 14-day trial) and the [Yosemite System Installer](https://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=915041082&mt=12)
- Right-click the 'Install OS X Yosemite.app' -> 'Show Package Contents'
- Mount ./Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg

  [image]
- Open the mounted 'OS X Install ESD'
- Open ./Packages/BaseSystemBinaries.pkg with Pacifist
- In the new Pacifist-window navigate to 'Content of BaseSystemBinaries/usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib'
- Right-click libxml2.2.dylib and install it
- Restart your Mac

Comment: I am in single user mode. I don't think I can right click. Maybe in recovery?

Comment: If I can do it from single user with no libxml then yes, my gf has a macbook air

Comment: Ok, well I have to wait until my gf gets home. Any tips to make the ssh login smooth? I'm in Berlin btw so she just left for work, no rush on any of this. I have all day.

Comment: I don't see Shared Support anywhere

Comment: Mine has no shared support, I have the exact same window as you but not that folder. Just checked the zip too, no shared support, am I downloading the wrong copy? I have 3.2.17

Comment: @RinconRex How big is your Yosemite Installation.app? Mine have 5.17 GB (10.0.1) and 5.19 GB (10.0.2 downloaded to the Applications folder yesterday!)

Comment: Actually it seems I am having trouble with Yosemite system installer being found.

Comment: @RinconRex Ahh ok. Do not right-click Pacifist (just install it somewhere) but 'Install Yosemite OS X.app' (i don't really know the english name of it) ;-)

Comment: Ok, finally got it all done. It took quite a long time to get Yosemite Installer downloaded. Also, I had to reinstall libxsml.1.dylib and libexsml.0.dylib as well. Any ideas why? I never touched either of them, doesnt seem possible that they both came up "wrong architecture".

Comment: @RinconRex No clue, probably the specific installer instructions demands to install the whole bunch of *xsml.dylibs.